# Why are Sempaphores limited in Linux

Tags: linux, semaphore

We just ran out of semaphores on our Linux box, due to the use of too many Websphere Message Broker instances or somesuch.

A colleague and I got to wondering why this is even limited - it's just a bit of memory, right?

I thoroughly googled and found nothing.

Anyone know why this is?

cheers

Comment: Maybe worth also asking on [Unix & Linux Stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). I am interested in an answer :-)

Comment: The number of semaphores is by default 128, but this is not a fixed value and can be changed at runtime. See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/how-do-i-increase-the-number-of-semaphore-arrays-in-linux) in [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's just a bit of memory, but that bit is in the kernel's memory space. You want to keep that as small as possible; you don't want a process to crash your box because it created more semaphores than you had memory for.

Comment: You can increase the number with `sysctl`... e.g. `sysctl -A | grep kernel.sem`

Answer (score 4):

Semaphores, when being used, require frequent access with very, very low overhead.

Having an expandable system where memory for each newly requested semaphore structure is allocated on the fly would introduce complexity that would slow down access to them because it would have to first look up where the particular semaphore in question at the moment is stored, then go fetch the memory where it is stored and check the value.    It is easier and faster to keep them in one compact block of fixed memory that is readily at hand.

Having them dispersed throughout memory via dynamic allocation would also make it more difficult to efficiently use memory pages that are locked (that is, not subject to being swapped out when there are high demands on memory).  The use of "locked in" memory pages for kernel data is especially important for time-sensitive and/or critical kernel functions.

Having the limit be a tunable parameter (see links in the comments of original question) allows it to be increased at runtime if needed via an "expensive" reallocation and relocation of the block.  But typically this is done one time at system initialization before anything much is even using semaphores.

That said, the amount of memory used by a semaphore set is rather tiny.  With modern memory available on systems being in the many gigabytes the original default limits on the number of them might seem a bit stingy.   But keep in mind that on many systems semaphores are rarely used by user space processes and the linux kernel finds its way into lots of small embedded systems with rather limited memory, so setting the default limit arbitrarily high in case it might be used seems wasteful.

The few software packages, such as Oracle database for example, that do depend on having many semaphores available, typically do recommend in their installation and/or system tuning advice to increase the system limits.